Combine types with intersect being required and difference being optional
We have an api returning data with slightly different data structures. The goal is to combine multiple types into a definition where properties that appear in both types being marked as required and non overlapping properties to be typed as optional.
Playground: Link
Updated Playground with ines modifications: Link
Input:
interface X {
  id: number;
  nonOptionalObject: {
    id: number;
    optional: string
  };
  foo: {
    bar: boolean
  };
  array: {
    hello: string
  }[];
  //bonus: string;
}

interface Y {
  id: number;
  additional: string;
  nonOptionalObject: {
    id: number;
  };
  array: {
    hello: string
   }[];
  //bonus: number;
}

Desired Result:
interface Combined{
   id: number;
   additional?: string;
   nonOptionalObject: {
     id: number;
     optional?: string
   }
   foo?: {
     bar: boolean;
   }
   array:{
     hello: string;
   };
   //bonus: string | number
}

With the following utility it almost works but typescript complains about the array
type Merge<T, U> = Partial<T & U> & (T | U);

type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends object
    ? U extends object
    ? {
        [K in keyof Merge<T, U>]: K extends keyof T
        ? K extends keyof U
        ? Exclude<DeepMerge<Exclude<T[K], undefined>, Exclude<U[K], undefined>>, undefined>
        : Exclude<T[K], undefined>
        : K extends keyof U
        ? Exclude<U[K], undefined>
        : never;
    }
    : T | U
    : T | U;


type mergedDefinition = DeepMerge<X, Y>;

//Optional properties also have an additional | undefined at the end which isn't really nice
const bookingResponse: mergedDefinition = {
    id: 0,
    nonOptionalObject: {
        id: 1
    },
    //Issue here
    array: []
};

//Accessing bookingResponse.id ... already gives good typings.

const genericFunc = <T extends mergedDefinition = mergedDefinition>() => { };
//Also issues here
genericFunc<X>();




I found a way to solve your problem. Try the solution below:
type ArrayType<T> =  T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;

type Merge<T, U> = Partial<T & U> & (T | U);

type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends object
    ? (U extends object
      ? {
          [K in keyof Merge<T, U>]: (K extends keyof T
          ? (K extends keyof U 
            ? (T[K] extends Array<ArrayType<T[K]>> 
              ?  T[K]
              : Exclude<DeepMerge<Exclude<T[K], undefined>, Exclude<U[K], undefined>>, undefined>)
            : Exclude<T[K], undefined>)
          : (K extends keyof U
            ? Exclude<U[K], undefined>
            : never));
      }
      : T | U)
    : T | U;

Code in playground
Update
Example with array type merging:
type ArrayType<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;

type Merge<T, U> = Partial<T & U> & (T | U);

type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends object
    ? (U extends object
        ? {
            [K in keyof Merge<T, U>]: (K extends keyof T
                ? (K extends keyof U
                    ? (T[K] extends Array<ArrayType<T[K]>>
                        ? (U[K] extends Array<ArrayType<T[K]>>
                            ? Array<DeepMerge<ArrayType<T[K]>, ArrayType<U[K]>>>
                            : T[K]|U[K])
                        : Exclude<DeepMerge<Exclude<T[K], undefined>, Exclude<U[K], undefined>>, undefined>)
                    : Exclude<T[K], undefined>)
                : (K extends keyof U
                    ? Exclude<U[K], undefined>
                    : never));
        }
        : T | U)
    : T | U;

Code in playground
Code with fix playground (return T[K]|U[K] instead of T[K])

Thank you, this is already going in the right direction. I think we also need to somehow deep merge the array in case that both types are arrays?
If we had an additional property Y.array.foo: string to the second  second interface it dissapears.
Do we also need to check the case where U[K] extends an array?

Yes, you can replace the first T[K] statement in a condition with a U[K] extends Array<ArrayType<U[K]>> ? Array<DeepMerge<ArrayType<T[K]>, ArrayType<U[K]>>> : T[K]  statement. I added an example.

Thanks once again. I updated the original post to include a link with nested array types and there it still seems to fail.

In your example you are merging arrays instead of array types (Array< DeepMerge<ArrayType<T[K]>, ArrayType<U[K]>> >). I changed the playground in the post example. You can see how it works with your test. Is this what you want to achieve?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
